# ECS - fargate task fails and starts for no reason

Tags: task, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

my cpu and memory utilization hasn't atlest reched 50% and we didn't change any configuration from our side.
My image and task definition is also not disturbed BUT MY TASK GOT STOPPED AND RESTARTED THE NEW TASK.

As i was checking about this error over internet, I found out that AWS updates the task sometimes for some reasons in Blue Green manner.

my files are very large i cant do download them directly while build stage So, My flask app contains two files onw is main model file and other prdictor file that contains all the paths. so my main file uses bert based tokenizer in which i have to pass the model files(that contains config and pytorch_model.bin files). so as i have lot of model files i used a seperate api path so that that downloads the model files from s3 to local(task level) and after this i can use my main api path for prediction

But my fargate running application is task dependent. i.e, i have to download some temporay file after the task is in running state.

So, whenever there is a task replaced i have to do some api hitting for file download in task locall in order my main api path to be running

So, can i know how to resolve this?

Comment: "whenever there is a task replaced i have to do some api hitting for file download in task locall in order my main api path to be running" I suggest you change your docker image to do that automatically on startup. Without much more details about what exactly it is doing, nobody is going to be able to give you much more help than that.

Comment: when my files are very large i cant do download them directly while build stage 

So, My flask app contains two files onw is main model file and other prdictor file that contains all the paths. so my main file uses bert based tokenizer in which i have to pass the model files(that contains config and pytorch_model.bin files).
so as i have lot of model files i used a seperate api path so that that downloads the model files from s3 to local(task level) and after this i can use my main api path for prediction.

Comment: OK, so have the docker container's startup script perform those downloads.

Comment: Im using the path because when evr there is a new model file addition i will just upload files in s3 an dhit the api

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that the manual steps you are taking to deploy your application cannot be scripted, but I'm not seeing anything in your comments that can't be automated. If nothing else, just configure ECS to pull an SSM parameter as an environment variable, and use that value as the S3 path to download. Then when you upload a new model file to S3, all you have to do is update your SSM parameter.